# Stub received bad data?

Tags: c#

Firstly, there is no problem executing the code on Win7/Win8 etc. The problem exists solely on Windows XP. The code is in a button, and basically runs taskmgr.exe as another users credentials (a local admin credentials, this is a Kiosk PC which loads a C# application which can be logged into and then load cmd.exe/taskmgr.exe as a local admin unaffected by the GPOs linked to the Kiosk user).

However, on XP, I get the error when clicking the button: Stub received bad data.

Code:

```
private void btnTaskMgr_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string password = "myPassword";
    SecureString secureString = new SecureString();

    foreach (char chr in password) secureString.AppendChar(chr);

    ProcessStartInfo processAdmin;
    processAdmin = new ProcessStartInfo();
    processAdmin.UseShellExecute = false;
    processAdmin.Password = secureString;
    processAdmin.UserName = "admin";
    processAdmin.FileName = "taskmgr.exe";
    processAdmin.WorkingDirectory = "C:\\Windows\\System32";
    Process.Start(processAdmin);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Is it XP SP3? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/897662

Comment: Yea, SP3'd and updated.

Comment: Just throwing ideas out here. Is `FileName = "taskmgr.exe"` sufficient? The [documentation for `CreateProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425(v=vs.85).aspx) says of `lpApplicationName` *In the case of a partial name, the function uses the current drive and current directory to complete the specification. The function will not use the search path*. I don't have any information that says whether `FileName` is mapped to `lpApplicationName` or `lpCommandLine`.

Comment: Works on Windows 7 no problem though

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Specify domain

processAdmin.Domain = "domain";