# WinSCP .NET Assembly impersonation issue: The stub received bad data

Tags: .net, impersonation, winscp, winscp-net

I have an .NET console app using WinSCP assembly version 5.19.5. The app is under impersonation in order to access files on NAS so that I set `ExecutableProcessUserName` and `ExecutableProcessPassword` for the `Session` object.

```
Dim sessionOptions As New SessionOptions
With sessionOptions
    .Protocol = Protocol.Sftp
    .HostName = _SFTPServer
    .UserName = _SFTPLoginID
    .Password = _SFTPLoginPwd
    .PortNumber = _SFTPPort
End With

sessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint =
    session.ScanFingerprint(sessionOptions, "SHA-256")

Using session As New Session
    session.ExecutableProcessUserName = _ServiceAccountUsername
    session.ExecutableProcessPassword =
        ConvertToSecureString(_ServiceAccountPassword)
    session.Open(sessionOptions)
```

It fails at `session.Open` with error:

> The stub received bad data
> Any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you need to specify the domain:
[Stub received bad data?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18807924/850848)

```
session.ExecutableProcessUserName = "user@domain";
```

---

*Side note: Setting `SessionOptions.SshHostKeyFingerprint` to the value returned by `session.ScanFingerprint` is just an ineffective equivalent of `SshHostKeyPolicy.GiveUpSecurityAndAcceptAny`.*